# Python: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'D'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am loading a train.csv file to fit it with a RandomForestClassifier.
The load and processing of the .csv file happens fine.I am able to play around with my dataframe.

When I try:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=150, min_samples_split=2, n_jobs=-1)
rf.fit(train, target)
```

I get this:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'D'
```

I have tried:

```
train=train.astype(float)
```

Replacing all 'D' with another value.

```
train.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

But the issue still persists.

I also tried printing all the valueErrors in my csv file, but cannot find a reference to 'D'.

This is my trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-9d8e309c06b6> in <module>()
----> 1 rf.fit(train, target)

\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    222 
    223         # Convert data
--> 224         X, = check_arrays(X, dtype=DTYPE, sparse_format="dense")
    225 
    226         # Remap output

\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_arrays(*arrays, **options)
    279                     array = np.ascontiguousarray(array, dtype=dtype)
    280                 else:
--> 281                     array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype)
    282                 if not allow_nans:
    283                     _assert_all_finite(array)

\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    460 
    461     """
--> 462     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    463 
    464 def asanyarray(a, dtype=None, order=None):

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'D'
```

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: You need to show us the file you're ready in. That's where the D comes from. Just a line or two should be fine, and the code where you load in your dataframe. The dataframe is not what you think it is.

Comment: This is what I've done:

`cols=['colname1','colname2'.....]`

`train = pd.read_csv("C://Train//Train.csv", names=cols, delimiter=',')`


This is a single row:

`5 146408P0015 34.856928 -82.439238 SA01 Greenville SC 29611 HXYF Greenville 0 0 0 0 0 HAXXF 0 0 Literacy Literacy & Language ESL Literacy & Language Books G61 AA B 266 0`

Comment: Why are you setting a comma as your delimiter when there are no commas?

Comment: Slater, I am reading out of a csv file, hence the comma. when i dont use the comma, the values are getting read with the default seperator as tab which is wrong.
An interesting note here is that, when i use comma, the dtype of all the columns is Object (which i am unable to convert to float)
When I don't use a comma as the seperator, the columns are float64 by default, which is what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Without RandomForestClassifier is not (as far as I could find) a python library (as included in python), it's difficult to know what's going on in your case. However, what's really happening there is that at some point, you're trying to transform a string 'D' into a float. 
I can reproduce your error by doing:

```
float('D')
```

Now, to be able to debug this problem, I recommend you to catch the exception:

```
try:
  rf.fit(train, target)
except ValueError as e:
  print(e)
  #do something clever with train and target like pprint them or something.
```

Then you can look into what's really going on. I couldn't find much about that random forest classifier except for this that might help:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/random-forest-classifier

Answer (score 0):

You should explore and clean your data. Probably you have a 'D' somewhere in your data which your code try to convert to a float. A trace within a "try-except" block is a good idea.